# Android studio does not display the logs using a real mobile

Tags: android-studio, debugging, logging, mobile

Android studio is not showing records to debug when using a real phone. Instead when using the emulator it prints all the registers. Any idea why this happens? What could be what is causing the problem?

As you can see here are introduced the Log.d and android studio does not detect nigun failure, as I say only prints the logs when I am using the emulator.

```
public class GPStracker implements LocationListener{
    Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "GPStracker";
    /*private static final String[] INITIAL_PERMS = {
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};


    private static final int INITIAL_REQUEST = 1337;

    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE = INITIAL_REQUEST + 4;*/

    public GPStracker(Context c){
        Log.d(TAG,"Entra en GPStracker");
        context = c;
    }

    public Location getLocation(){
       /* if (!permissionsGranted()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);
        } else doLocationAccessRelatedJob();*/

        /*int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);*/
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            Log.d(TAG,"Entra en GPStracker Getlocation");
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean isGpsEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(isGpsEnabled){
                Log.d(TAG,"Entra Mandando localizacion");
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,6000,10,this);
                Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                Log.d(TAG,"Entra Mandando localizacion antes return");

                try {
                    return l;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                boolean b = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please Enable GPS"+b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return null;
        } else {

            // Show rationale and request permission.
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error no permisos",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Add some more info like code snippet.

Comment: Are you using Huawei?

Comment: I edited and put my code. No im using meizu emulator with nexus 5 oneplus one and one huawei